# Link from external page to ember route

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an Ember app which is run using engines (So there are other apps as well)
In my app, I have the following route defined in addon\routes.js
this.route('my-route');

My question is, say from some other app (which does not use Ember), can I have the following link called as say href of an anchor tag

OR browser redirect & it would deep route to where I want ?

https://abc.xyz.com/xyz/123/ui/#/myapp/my-route?action=123

I ultimately hope to get the control in my-route (after the other app hits the above URL)

Comment: Well, if you use the `locationType:hash` then yes. But what should `action=someAction` do?

Comment: I need the someAction to be available in the model hook of "my-route"

Comment: Well, you have to specify it as query-param, but then this will just work.